# How to train a tree classifier with string labels and features?

Tags: python, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, classification, decision-tree

Below is my code:

```
import sklearn
#features = [[140,"smooth"],[130,"smooth"],[150,"bumpy"],[170,"bumpy"]]
#labels = ["apple","apple","orange","orange"]

# Now replace 1 for smooth & 0 for bumpy and 0 for apple & 1 for orange
features = [[140,1],[130,1],[150,0],[170,0]]
labels = [0,0,1,1]

# Now I train a classifier
from sklearn import tree

my_classifier = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
my_classifier.fit(features,labels)
predict = my_classifier.predict([[150,0]])
print(predict)
```

How can I train a classifier without converting it to numbers?

e.g. I want below lines of code to classify my classifier. Please suggest, thanks in advance:)

```
features = [[140,"smooth"],[130,"smooth"],[150,"bumpy"],[170,"bumpy"]]
labels = ["apple","apple","orange","orange"]
```

Comment: It is said in the tutorial. But you can use any type as labels or features.

Comment: For targets (labels) you dont need the conversion, it will be handled by scikit. But for features you need to convert them

Comment: I deleted "...in supervised learning" because that's superfluous. I retitled "string labels and features" because those are different things, and they get handled differently, both algorithmically and for encoding in sklearn (depends on the type of classifier: tree-based, NN, etc.). (Also, string features typically require normalization, string labels don't.)

Comment: There are already [124 questions for classifier string features](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+classifier+string+features), mostly Python. Which one should be canonical?

Answer (score 0):

Because of the way the algorithms work under the hood, your labels and features are always going to get converted to one-hot vectors at some point.

You can just maintain a dictionary of which index of the vector represents which label and turn them back after inference.

Comment: String features should be treated as categoricals, not integer. Also, we generally first do some normalization (strip non-meaningful case, whitespace, punctuation and digits, maybe lemmatize) and misspelling-tolerant lookup (e.g. Levenshtein distance)

Comment: @smci Generally when categories are well-defined like (hard, easy) or (smooth, bumpy) or (high, medium, low) etc, we would not need the other normalization processes you described), but +1 for Levenshtein Distance :)

Comment: @smci True, inside it's probably going to get converted to one-hot vectors rather than integers. However, AFAIK scikit-learn doesn't accept one-hot vector input or output for labels, and instead accepts integers. Feel free to correct me if I'm wrong and I'll change the answer.

Comment: Guys, have tried below,it's working but I'm sure there would be another nice wayt to do it, in case my features increases:from sklearn import preprocessing
        encoder = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
        encodeValues = 
        encoder.fit_transform(["smooth","smooth","bumpy","bumpy"])
        print(encodeValues)
        features = [[140,1],[130,1],[150,0],[170,0]]
        decodedValues = encoder.inverse_transform([1,1,0,0])
        print(decodedValues)

Comment: @Ashish.k You are going in the correct direction. There's no nicer way to do it. Only correct ways, and that's one-hot encoding. Here when you say smooth=1 and bumpy=0, the model may assume that the smooth is ordered higher than bumpy, which is not relevant when your categories dont contain any order in them.

Comment: @Omegastick Scikit-learn handles labels on its own. Be it binary and multi-class. For multi-label cases, it does accept a label-indicator matrix (which is infact a one-hot encoded array with 1 in all the labels present in the particular sample).

Comment: @VivekKumar I just looked it up, and so it does. Edited my answer.

Comment: Labels will be converted to integers only. For label-indicator matrix, we have to explicitly convert that, scikit wont do it automatically. For features, scikit wont do anything automatically. We have to handle them ourselves.

Comment: @VivekKumar: yes this example wouldn't need normalization, since it has crisp labels and features, but the general title is disagreeing with the more specific question body. Which is bad for this being canonical, and for findability.